# How to get user's input in both int and float for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

How to get user's input in both int and float for python3?

> Apparently programmed a calculator, but i would love for user's input to be in int and float not just int or float but both. That's basically all am concerned about, changing the int to get int and float. Sadly Java uses double.

```
def calculator():
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    def sub(x, y):
        return x - y

    def mul(x, y):
        return x * y

    def div(x, y):
        return x / y

    def power(x, y):
        return x ** y

    def modulus(x, y):
        return x % y

    print(""" -- Select Operation --
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Power
    6. Modulus
    """)

    choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 from the Select Operation >> ")
    while choice not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'):
        choice = input("Invalid Input! Please Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 from the Select Operation >> ")
    print("\n")
    print("============================================================")
    print("Gathering data...")
    # How to make user input in both int and float not int alone?
    num1 = int(input("Enter First number >> "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter Second number >> "))

    if choice == '1':
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '2':
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", sub(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '3':
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", mul(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '4':
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", div(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '5':
        print(num1, "^", num2, "=", power(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '6':
        print(num1, "%", num2, "=", modulus(num1, num2))
    repeat_cal()

def repeat_cal():
    print("Do you want to Select Operation again")
    choose_again = input("Enter Y for YES or N for NO>> ")
    if choose_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculator()
    elif choose_again.upper() == 'N':
        print("-----------------Good Bye!---------------------------")
        exit()
    else:
        repeat_cal()

calculator()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Your question isn't yet clear; as recommended in the intro tour you took, please give examples of what you're trying to do, as well as the code you've already attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take input as decimal.Decimal using the string constructor to avoid floating point precision loss. Decimal can represent any arbitrary precision including integers and will always return a value that would be expected from a calculator.

```
def calculator():
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    def sub(x, y):
        return x - y

    def mul(x, y):
        return x * y

    def div(x, y):
        return x / y

    def power(x, y):
        return x ** y

    def modulus(x, y):
        return x % y

    print(""" -- Select Operation --
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Power
    6. Modulus
    """)
    from decimal import Decimal
    choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 from the Select Operation >> ")
    while choice not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'):
        choice = input("Invalid Input! Please Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 from the Select Operation >> ")
    print("\n")
    print("============================================================")
    print("Gathering data...")
    # How to make user input in both int and float not int alone?
    num1 = Decimal(input("Enter First number >> "))
    num2 = Decimal(input("Enter Second number >> "))

    if choice == '1':
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", str(add(num1, num2)))
    elif choice == '2':
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", str(sub(num1, num2)))
    elif choice == '3':
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", str(mul(num1, num2)))
    elif choice == '4':
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", str(div(num1, num2)))
    elif choice == '5':
        print(num1, "^", num2, "=", str(power(num1, num2)))
    elif choice == '6':
        print(num1, "%", num2, "=", str(modulus(num1, num2)))
    repeat_cal()

def repeat_cal():
    print("Do you want to Select Operation again")
    choose_again = input("Enter Y for YES or N for NO>> ")
    if choose_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculator()
    elif choose_again.upper() == 'N':
        print("-----------------Good Bye!---------------------------")
        exit()
    else:
        repeat_cal()

calculator()
```

Comment: Thanks the *Decimal* works.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to just take the input as a float. That way, if the user inputs a float, you can support it.

If the user inputs an int, it will also be supported. If, for some reason, you want to check if the input is an int, you can just check if the number has a 0 after the decimal.